How to interpret keras lstm layer weights?
I have to implement lstm in hardware so I have a small testing model of lstm to understand the extracted weights from the keras model.
input_ppg = Input(shape=(10,1), name='ppg_input')
conv_ppg1 = Conv1D(4, kernel_size=3,activation="relu", kernel_constraint=max_norm(3))(input_ppg)
max_ppg1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv_ppg1)
bilstm_ppg = LSTM(4,activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, kernel_constraint=max_norm(3)(max_ppg1)
flat = Flatten()(bilstm_ppg)
output = Dense(2, activation='linear')(flat)
model = Model(inputs=input_ppg, outputs=output)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, clipvalue=1.0)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error')

I have attached the model summary picture. To extract the weights I have used the following code.
lstm_weights = model.layers[3].get_weights()
for i in lstm_weights:
    print(i.shape)

The above code gave me the shapes of the weights and bias of lstm layer.
(4, 16)
(4, 16)
(16,)
LSTM EQUATIONS
MODEL SUMMARY
Can Anyone map these weights to the actual weights given in the equations of lstm??
Which one is Wf,Wo,Wi,Wc,....... all weights
